# Iterate only lines only available at beginning of open

Tags: python

I'm creating a program that should create a file with every possible combination of given characters and put them in a file. It will of course go until I stop it or until I run out of memory obviously.

Though, my idea is that the code reads the file and iterates over THOSE lines, while making new lines. I do not want it to iterate over the new lines though, which it is doing. Any help?

```
import time, os

char_list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
start_time = time.time()
password = "aaa"
file_name = "file.txt"

with open(file_name, "w+") as f:
    for i in char_list:
        f.write(i+"\n") 

with open(file_name, "a+") as f:
    for x in f:
        for i in char_list:
            f.write(x[:-1]+i+"\n")
            print(x[:-1]+i)
            if x[:-1]+i == password:
                    break


print("%s was found after %ss!"%(password, time.time()-start_time))

input()
```

Comment: Any reason you can't put the code in the question instead of pastebin?

Comment: I wasn't very familiar with how it worked, I'll try now.

Comment: What do you mean by any help? What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: Is there some reason you're writing all those strings to a file? You don't need to do that if you're just trying to create all the combinations until you find the one equal to `password`.

Comment: BTW, it's inefficient to create the `x[:-1]+i` string 3 times in that inner loop.

Comment: My question is: How do I only read the lines that were in a file before it was opened, while still writing to the file.

I'm using a file because when I use lists I get memory errors.

Comment: You don't need to use lists either. You use an iterator. I'll post a simple demo if you like.

Comment: That'd be great, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To form these combinations we can use the [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function, which creates the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the iterables you pass it. This function returns an iterator, so you can loop over the tuples it yields without having to store them into a list.

Here's a small demo that you can modify for your purposes.

```
from itertools import product

def all_products(char_list, password):
    count = 1
    while True:
        for t in product(char_list, repeat=count):
            s = ''.join(t)
            print(s, end=', ')
            if s == password:
                return
        count += 1

all_products('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'help')
print()
```

This program is very simple, so you will have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to kill it if you get impatient waiting for it to generate a large password.